# Basic Authentication for Swagger2 in Spring - XML configuration

Tags: java, spring-security, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am new to `Swagger`. I already configured Swagger2 (XML configuration) with Spring using this [documentation](https://dzone.com/articles/xml-based-swagger-2-configuration-with-spring-mvc). I'm already using custom authentication in my app using Spring security. Now, Swagger url's (`/swagger-ui.html`, `/v2/api-docs`) are skipped from these authentication. But, I have to add a basic authentication to the swagger endpoints with a configurable username and password. I didn't find any XML based configurations for this. Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT : swagger and swagger ui version : 2.5.0